# Fading HTML elements in and out after timed delays using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I recently launched my first website, and despite being very proud of how far I've come, I know that my code is more "*I got it to work*" than "*It works the best that it can.*" I'd like some criticism, and insight into how you would accomplish the same effect.

This script shows and hides overlapping Divs to tell a story through text about myself. I want to retain the granular control over how long each div stays visible, but simplify this code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button.button").click(function(){
      $("h1.about-title").fadeOut(300, function() {
       $("div.b").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(4000).fadeOut(300, function(){
        $("div.c").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(4000).fadeOut(300, function(){
         $("div.d").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(4000).fadeOut(300, function(){
          $("div.e").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(300, function(){
           $("div.f").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(300, function(){
            $("div.g").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(5000).fadeOut(300, function(){
             $("div.h").delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(4000).fadeOut(300, function(){

               });         
              });          
             });          
            });   
           });         
          });
         }); 
        });
       }); 
      });
</script>
```

an example of this running can be found at http://www.erikgratz.com/about.html

I suspect I could have saved a lot of time and code with a loop or some variables. How would you accomplish this same effect?

Comment: You might want to change the title to "My life story in JavaScript. It might get more interest. You're Javascript code will be reviewed anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### Explicit question

> Criticize my Javascript

So... you have some JavaScript that uses the jQuery library, and there are a lot of nested function calls. Obviously that isn't very flexible, and some might say it looks daunting with all of those nested callbacks.

### Implicit question

#### i.e. How can I simplify this?

There are numerous ways to achieve this... but one way is to use [function partials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) to simplify the callbacks.

Consider the function below, which checks for a next sibling element using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next):

```
function fadeInOutNext(elementCollection) {
   elementCollection.delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(getDelayForElement(elementCollection)).fadeOut(300, function() {
     const next = elementCollection.next();
     if (next) {
       fadeInOutNext(next);
     }
   });
 }
```

With this function, the nested callbacks can be reduced:

```
$("button.button").click(function(){
 $("h1.about-title").fadeOut(300, fadeInOutNext.bind(null, $("div.b")));
});
```

As well as the function to get the delay between fading in and out:

```
function getDelayForElement(elementCollection) {
  if (elementCollection.is('.e, .f, .g')) {
    return 5000;
  }
  return 4000;
}
```

See the complete code in the snippet below:

```js
 function getDelayForElement(elementCollection) {
  if (elementCollection.is('.e, .f, .g')) {
    return 5000;
  }
  return 4000;
 }
 function fadeInOutNext(elementCollection) {
   elementCollection.delay(500).fadeIn(300).delay(getDelayForElement(elementCollection)).fadeOut(300, function() {
     const next = elementCollection.next();
     if (next) {
       fadeInOutNext(next);
     }
   });
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("button.button").click(function(){
     $("h1.about-title").fadeOut(300, fadeInOutNext.bind(null, $("div.b")));
   });
 });
```

```css
/* ------------------------------THE RESET----------------------------*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*-----------MY CODE-----------*/

* {
  font-family: Futura, Futura-Medium, "Futura Medium", "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  color: white
}

.frontpage {
  font-family: Futura, Futura-Medium, "Futura Medium", "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px black;
}

.frontname {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}

.navbar {
  font-family: Futura, Futura-Medium, "Futura Medium", "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding 0px;
}

.name {
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.links {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em .45em;
}

.list {
  font-size: .45em;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagetitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.SDmain {
  margin-top: 45px;
}

/*----------PAGE SPECIFIC STYLES-----------*/

.contactinfo {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.contact-social-media-block {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%)
}

.sm {}

.contact-social-media {
  height: 8vh;
  width: 8vw;
}

.email-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.about-title {
  font-size: 10em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.about-body {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.b {
  display: none;
}

.c {
  display: none;
}

.d {
  display: none;
}

.e {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.f {
  display: none;
}

.g {
  display: none;
}

.h {
  display: none;
}

.article {
  color: white;
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.article-title {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.article-sub,
.article-date,
.port-sub {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-style: italic;
}

.article-body,
.port-desc {
  text-indent: 1.75em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.port-table {
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1.25em;
}

.port-row {
  display: table-row;
  margin-top: 1.25em;
}

.port-image {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
}

.port-text {
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  width: 55%;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
}

.port-title {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*-----------Animations and JQuery---------*/

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%)
}

.preopen {
  left: 150% !important;
}

.open {
  left: 50% !important;
}

.closed {
  left: -50% !important;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}

.preopen2 {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.open2 {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.closed2 {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.transition2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

#text1 {
  min-width: 67vw;
}

/*------------------FERNTS-----------------*/

@font-face {
  font-family: Futura;
  src: url(fonts/futuramedium.otf) format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Futura-Medium;
  src: url(fonts/futural-webfont.svg);
}

/*----------VIDJER---------*/

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

/*-----------MEDIA QUERIES-------------*/

@media all and (min-width: 1800px) {
  .frontname {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
  .list {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .break {
    display: none;
  }
  .contactinfo {
    font-size: 4em;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
  }
  .pagetitle {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: 11em;
  }
  .navbar {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .about-title {
    font-size: 40em;
  }
  .port-row {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .article {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1799px) {
  .frontname {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .list {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .break {
    display: none;
  }
  .contactinfo {
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
  }
  .pagetitle {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: 5em;
  }
  .navbar {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .break {
    display: none;
  }
  .contactinfo {
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
  }
  .pagetitle {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: 4.5em;
  }
  .navbar {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .frontname {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
  .list {
    font-size: .6em
  }
  .contactinfo {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
  }
  .pagetitle {
    padding-top: 1em;
    font-size: 4.5em;
  }
  .navbar {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 599px) {
  .frontname {
    font-size: 1.4em
  }
  .list {
    font-size: .6em
  }
  .contactinfo {
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  .pagetitle {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .navbar {
    font-size: .5em;
  }
  .about-title {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="SDmain">
  <h2 class="pagetitle"></h2>
  <h1 class="about-title" id="text0">Hello</h1>
  <div class="about-body b" id="text1">
    <p>Welcome.<br>My name is Erik. <br>I enjoy Minimalism.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body c">
    <p>I made this happen with<br>Javascript and JQuery.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body d">
    <p>I like Java as well.<br>Programs just make sense to me.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body e">
    <p>I have made apps for android, websites for my friends, and I am looking for new projects.<br>You can find my other works in the Portfolio.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body f">
    <p>I write about my life occasionally. If that interests you, it drains out of my head into my Blog.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body g">
    <p>I am currently seeking my first job in Software Development.<br><br>My Resume can be found on the Contact page.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about-body h">
    <p>Thank you for reading.
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="button" id="b"> Play </button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an alternative solution, which uses CSS animation.

Since the rest of divs (from ".b" to ".h") have the same effects, I added it to an animation name called *intro*, and the hello is using a fade animation called *fade*, and last thing is to use JavaScript to add the *ani* class to each div for different timing.

add the code below to **style.css**:

```
@keyframes fade{
    from{
        opacity: 1
    }
    to{
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@keyframes intro{
    0%{
        opacity:0;
    }
    30%,70%{
        opacity:1;
    }
    100%{
        opacity:0;
    }
}
.SDmain>*{
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
.about-title.ani{
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
.about-body.ani{
    display:block;
    animation-name: intro;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

Then JavaScript can be as simple as:

```
let startingTime=-1500;
const gap=3000;
const startAniWhen=selector=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $(selector).addClass("ani");
    },startingTime+=gap);
}

$(".button").click(()=>{
    $(".about-title").addClass("ani");
    for(let x of [".b",".c",".d",".e",".f",".g",".h"]) startAniWhen(x);
});
```

see example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5714xdca/)

Comment: I think using css is for best practice and better performance(this might be subtle to see)